# Build tools broken after uninstalling Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, makefile

When I use make to build my C++ project from the command line (`cmake ..`, `make`) after installing and uninstalling xcode, make outputs `make[2]: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++: No such file or directory`

`xcode-select -p` output:
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

`sudo xcode-select --install` output:
`xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

`xcode-select --reset` output: nothing

I uninstalled and reinstalled the xcode command line tools and it still gives the same No such file or directory error

Comment: Did you cleared the CMake cache, i.e. deleted the CMakeCache.txt file in the build folder after those changes? CMake caches many values from system introspection in this file.

Comment: That works, thank you! Now I see the bugs in my code Please add that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake stores the results of its system introspection - the full path to the compiler used is one of them - in a file called CMakeCache.txt.
If you change something in your system that invalidates these results you need to clear the cache, i.e. delete the CMakeCache.txt file in the build folder.